# Using two variables for fill parameter in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar questions have been asked before (e.g., [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429822/two-fill-variable-in-ggplot); [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795226/how-to-use-fill-in-ggplot-with-two-sets-of-factor-variables)), however, the answers seem to be missing the point; also, my question is slightly different. Here is the base plot:

[image]

And this is the code that created it:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=a2.st, aes(x=Type, y=lFreq, fill=factor(Hit))) +
    geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity', width=0.5) +
    scale_x_discrete(name='Type',
        breaks=breaks, labels=labels) +
    scale_y_continuous('Frequency', limits=c(0, 240)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c('#d95f02','#1b9e77'), name='Hit:',
        breaks=c('0','1'),
        labels=c('yes','no')) +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=11),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10))
p1
```

Instead of one stacked bar for a level of `Type`, is there a way to add three more bars such that `Type` differentiates between four levels of another variable? In other words, each `Type` would group four levels of variable `Level`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `interaction()` to specify the fill (e.g. `fill = interaction(Type, Level)`) or create it as a separate variable beforehand, if its easier, and then specify a `scale_fill_manual` to make sure you get the colors right.

In my experience, the hard part is producing a legend that is not horrible.  The best strategy I've found is the one used to make [bivariate choropleths](http://lenkiefer.com/2017/04/24/bivariate-map/), but it is a lot of work, and might be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

After some exploration, it seems more efficient to use a mosaic plot utilising the power of `ggmosaic` package, for example:

```
require(ggmosaic)

newdf = olddf[rep(1:nrow(olddf), olddf$Freq),]
mosaic1 <- ggplot(data=newdf) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x=product(Hit, Type, Level), fill=Hit)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5)) + 
  labs(y='Y', x='X', title='TITLE')
mosaic1
```

Fantastic resource can be found here: [Generalized Mosaic Plots in the ggplot2 Framework](https://journal.r-project.org/articles/RJ-2023-013/)