# Using patterns instead of colours in mosaic plot with `ggmosaic` in `R`

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmosaic

Following [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926959/tidying-labels-for-ggmosaic-plot) I was wondering if `ggmosaic` allows use of patterns rather than colours, maybe with `ggpatterns`?

From that previous post, the example dataset is:

```
dat = data.frame(
    Correct=c('no','yes','no','yes','no','yes','no','yes',
        'no','yes','no','yes','no','yes','no','yes'),
    Type=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B',
        'A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
    Level=c('1st','1st','1st','1st','2nd','2nd','2nd','2nd',
        '1st','1st','1st','1st','2nd','2nd','2nd','2nd'),
    Class=c('X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X',
        'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'),
    Percent=c(69.98,30.02,71.17,28.83,42.17,57.83,69.47,30.53,
        18.68,81.32,26.92,73.08,13.48,86.52,22.65,77.35)
)
```

Then, combine the original code with that from [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan):

```
library(ggmosaic)

mosaic1 <- ggplot(data=dat) +
    geom_mosaic(aes(weight=Percent, 
        x=product(Type, Level),
        conds=product(Class),
        fill=Correct)) +
    scale_y_productlist(breaks=c(.25,.75), labels=c('1st','2nd'),
        expand = c(0, 0.01)) +
  scale_x_productlist(expand=c(0,0.01)) +
    ggtitle('TITLE') +
    theme_tufte(base_family='sans') +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1, size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=11),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        legend.title=element_text(size=11))
mosaic1
```

How can one replace colours with patterns, e.g., using `ggpattern`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to use the new features introduced with `ggplot2 3.5.0` (and `R >= 4.2.0`) which bring native support of patterns to `ggplot2`. There is still some room for a more user-friendly API to specify patterns, i.e. as of the moment we have to specify the patterns from scratch using grobs, but it works well with the default geoms and scales, and also with `ggmosaic`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)
library(ggthemes)
library(grid)

packageVersion("ggplot2")
#> [1] '3.5.0'
packageVersion("ggmosaic")
#> [1] '0.3.4'

patterns <- list(
  pattern(
    rectGrob(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0.25, 0.75), width = 1, height = 0.5),
    height = unit(5, "mm"), 
    extend = "repeat",
    gp = gpar(fill = "#b2182b")
  ),
  pattern(
    rectGrob(x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = c(0.25, 0.75), width = 0.5, height = 0.5),
    width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"), extend = "repeat",
    gp = gpar(fill = "#1b7837")
  )
)

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(
    weight = Percent,
    x = product(Type, Level),
    conds = product(Class),
    fill = Correct
  ), color = "grey40") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = patterns
  ) +
  scale_y_productlist(
    breaks = c(.25, .75), 
    labels = c("1st", "2nd"),
    expand = c(0, 0.01)
  ) +
  scale_x_productlist(expand = c(0, 0.01)) +
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  theme_tufte(base_family = "sans") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      angle = 45, hjust = 1,
      vjust = 1, size = 10
    ),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 11)
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** Using `linesGrob` for the patterns we could get vertical and horizontal lines using this specification for the patterns:

```
patterns <- list(
  pattern(
    linesGrob(
      x = c(0, 1), y = c(0.5, 0.5)
    ),
    height = unit(3, "mm"),
    extend = "repeat",
    gp = gpar(col = "#b2182b", lwd = unit(5, "mm"), fill = NA)
  ),
  pattern(
    linesGrob(
      x = c(0.5, 0.5), y = c(0, 1)
    ),
    width = unit(3, "mm"),
    extend = "repeat",
    gp = gpar(col = "#1b7837", lwd = unit(5, "mm"), fill = NA)
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan)! Can one use `linesGrob` for horizontal and vertical lines instead?

Comment: Sure. See my update for a specs of the patterns using `linesGrob`. But I have to admit that I still struggle too on how to define the right specs. (:

Answer (score 2):

It seems `geom_mosiac_pattern()` is not an option, so here is a workaround. I've included a comprehensive (but not exhaustive) amount of pattern variables for you to adapt at your leisure.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

dat <- data.frame(
  Correct=c('no','yes','no','yes','no','yes','no','yes',
            'no','yes','no','yes','no','yes','no','yes'),
  Type=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B',
         'A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
  Level=c('1st','1st','1st','1st','2nd','2nd','2nd','2nd',
          '1st','1st','1st','1st','2nd','2nd','2nd','2nd'),
  Class=c('X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X',
          'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'),
  Percent=c(69.98,30.02,71.17,28.83,42.17,57.83,69.47,30.53,
            18.68,81.32,26.92,73.08,13.48,86.52,22.65,77.35))

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(xlabels = factor(paste0(Type, ":", Class), 
                          levels = c("A:X", "B:X", "A:Y", "B:Y")),
         Level = factor(Level, levels = c("2nd", "1st")))

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(x = xlabels, y = Percent, pattern = Correct, group = Level),
                   colour = "black",
                   width = 1,
                   fill = NA,
                   pattern_density = 0.5,
                   pattern_spacing = .03,
                   pattern_fill = NA,
                   pattern_colour = "grey50",
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6,
                   inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c("stripe", "crosshatch")) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(50, 150),
                     labels = c("1st", "2nd"),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(title = "TITLE", x = "Type:Class", y = "Correct:Level") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1, size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=11),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10),
        legend.title=element_text(size=11))
```

[image: result]